# EmberJS - Assertion failed: The value that #each loops over must be an Array. You passed (generated application controller)

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I'm struggling to get my model's fixture data to render to my template, I receive the error above when I try an each loop in my template:

```
{{#each}}
    {{title}}
{{/each}}
```

I have set up my router like so:

```
Application.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('application', { path: '/' });
});

Application.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('applicationmodel');
    }
});
```

And my model is setup like so:

```
Application.ApplicationModel = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string')
});

Application.ApplicationModel.FIXTURES = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: 'title-1'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: 'title-2'
    }
];
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: It's working for me, do you not have an adapter defined?  Additionally it should be `applicationModel` when querying the store  http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/295/edit

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
{{#each content}}
   {{title}}
{{/each}}
```

and

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({}) 

Application.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('applicationModel');
    },
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        controller.set('content', model);
    }
});
```

EDIT: To elaborate as per @Andy Hayden's request in the comments:

The error (`EmberJS - Assertion failed: The value that #each loops over must be an Array. You passed (generated application controller)`) gives us two clues:

1. Whatever we are trying to loop over is not an Array. From the template we can see that we are looping over the `content` property of our controller. Thus it looks like we don't have an `ArrayController` set up and we are dealing with an `ObjectController`. You could confirm this by using [Ember Inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ember-inspector/bmdblncegkenkacieihfhpjfppoconhi?hl=en)
2. Where does the controller come from? Ember will [auto generate](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/routing/generated-objects/) controllers for us if it needs one and we don't explicitly define it. We can see that that is, in fact, what happened, by looking at the error message (`generated application controller`). Ember wouldn't know if we want to represent a single object or an array, so it generated an `ObjectController` for us. If we explicitly define up an `ApplicationController` of type `ArrayController`, Ember will use our controller instead of generating one itself.

Comment: Doing this removes the error and the template renders, however its not looping through the titles, ember inspector also thinks there are no records in the model, is this the problem maybe?

Comment: Whoops, that should've been `applicationModel` instead of `application`. I updated my answer. Could you try that and if it doesn't work set up a jsBin?

Comment: Have tried, made a JSBin http://jsbin.com/yonuxizi/1/edit. Its funny, it works on JSBin but the error occurs on my local machine. Maybe thats they key to my issue??

Comment: That's strange. Is it the exact same code? Also are you using the same Ember version on your local machine?

Comment: Would be great if you could say *why* you think that trying this would solve it. It doesn't for me, and this answer helps not at all in explaining why that might be.

Comment: Sure thing, Andy. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
Application.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('application', { path: '/' });
});

Application.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('application');
    }
});
```

And my model is setup like so:

```
Application.Application = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string')
});


Application.Application.FIXTURES = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: 'title-1'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: 'title-2'
    }
];
```

Try making the above changes.  Specifically, remove 'model' from the names and make sure there isn't a space before FIXTURES.

```
{{#each app in model}}
     {{app.title}}
{{/each}}
```

And then use `model`, since it's the model property that you're iterating over.

Comment: Again, the error's gone but I'm getting no output. Should ember inspector be showing that my model has records in it with fixtures?

Comment: Yes, it should.  I've edited my reply.  Try it and see if it works.

Comment: Oops, forgot the `in` in the `each` helper.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error because the controller that your template is looping through is not enumerable - Ember is generating an `ApplicationController` for you automatically because you didn't specifically define one.

Simply declare an `ApplicationController` like the following:

`App.ApplicationController = Ember.ArrayController.extend()`

Comment: I've done this now and also set up an Object Controller for my model but still getting the same error. Looks like its not picking up my controller?

Answer (score 0):

Did you find an answer to this? Are you using Ember AppKit? If so, I just had this problem (which is how I ended up on SO) and it ended up being a file naming thing.

For example, in our other (non-EAK) Ember apps I would normally put `PostsController` inside a file named `posts_controller.js`. EAK doesn't seem to like that; it wants you to put it in `posts.js`, and if it doesn't find it, it won't return an ArrayController, so the template doesn't have anything to `{{#each}}` over.

Both my co-worker and I were bitten by this problem in our (different) EAK apps. We tracked it down by noticing that the console logging was reporting a generated controller when we had expected it to be loading the controller we had specified.

Answer (score 0):

If none of the other answers help, you might have mistyped the template name or the attribute of your `handlebars` script tag.

Check your `index.html` and make sure the `<script>` tag has the attibute `data-template-name="application"`

Should be something like this:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
```